JavaFX WebView shows Rectangles for line breaks in HTML Source
I use a JavaFX WebView control to display some static HTML documents inside my application. Unfortunately, the line breaks from the HTML file are displayed as rectangles in the WebView.
For the snippet below from the HTML file it looks like the screen shot underneath:
<p>Users can also have roles within the application, and they can be
    members of groups; both can be defined freely, although some sample roles
    and groups will be created with the installation.</p>




Note the rectangles between be members and roles and. When copying the sequence and pasting it to a text editor, there are no special characters (therefore I have to present a screen shot here …).
Use this MWE to reproduce the issue:
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MWE extends Application
{

    public static void main( String... args )
    {
        launch( args );
    }

    public void start( Stage primaryStage )
    {
        primaryStage.setTitle( "Minimal Working Example" );

        final var webView = new WebView();

        webView.getEngine().loadContent(
            """
            <p>Users can also have roles within the application, and they can be
              members of groups; both can be defined freely, although some sample roles
              and groups will be created with the installation.</p>
            """
        );

        final var vBox = new VBox( webView );
        final var scene = new Scene( vBox, 960, 600 );

        primaryStage.setScene( scene );
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}

I am using Java 21.0.1 with JavaFX 21.0.3 on Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS. And originally, the HTML is read from a file.
Just as a side node: when I translate a Markdown file to HTML and display the result, I see the same rectangles on where the Markdown source had the line breaks.
Any ideas how I could get rid of those rectangles? Other than reformatting the HTML, of course.

Seems to be a bug. I can reproduce the problem on Windows 11 using JavaFX 21.0.3. Problem appears to have been fixed by JavaFX 22.0.1. If you can, upgrade JavaFX.

Did you copy the text from somewhere? Sometimes there are special characters which look like a normal characters but they are not. The rectangles in your screenshot appear instead of spaces. You could try to remove the parts and type them manually by hand without copy paste to make sure, that they are "normal" characters. Rectangles or questionmark-symbols usually appears in fonts when the given characters is not supported, because of the font or the encoding.

@DavidWeber – No, I did not copy the text from somewhere, so I can exclude that there are invisible characters. The rectangles are there for line breaks in the HTML source code – that should be replaced by blanks or spaces by the HTML parser. So thank you for your tips, but I am already far, far, very far ahead of them.
